# How do I find a disabled index on SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

A while back when I was performing some bulk inserts of data into my SQL Server database, I disabled a number of indexes to improve the insert performance.  I now need to go back and rebuild/re-enable them.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly which indexes I disabled.

Is there a way I can query to identify which indexes are disabled and should be re-enabled?

Comment: Why is this not in the IDE!! How hard is it to gray something out?

Comment: Here I am exactly four years to the day later with the same question :-/

Comment: @Simon_Weaver amen brother. Bizarre that SSMS just shows the index like any other, and only when you script it out does it show a final line where it disables itself...

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
select
    sys.objects.name as table_name,
    sys.indexes.name as index_name
from sys.indexes
    inner join sys.objects on sys.objects.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
where sys.indexes.is_disabled = 1
order by
    sys.objects.name,
    sys.indexes.name
```