# When an index got disabled

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have recently faced some issue with performance and while troubleshooting index were disabled on few tables. But I didn't get detail of when these got disabled.
I've checked the "sys.indexes"table but there's no such information available.

Comment: Check is_disabled in sys.indexes

Comment: I'd recommend to start tracking all DDL commands on your database. Thus you'd have date, name and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is "no, it's not available in hindsight". However, if this is the sort of information you're interested in knowing for when it happens next time, I'd set up either a DDL trigger or event notification on DDL events to store that information off somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you;

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(si.object_id) AS table_name, i.name AS indexname, sc.name column_name
FROM sys.index_columns si
     JOIN sys.columns sc ON sc.object_id = si.object_id
                            AND si.column_id = sc.column_id
     LEFT JOIN SYS.indexes i ON si.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE i.is_unique = 1;
```

Comment: I am asking for "when indexes got disabled".

Answer (score -1):

It is there on stack overflow ...
[Find disabled indexes ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495446/how-do-i-find-a-disabled-index-on-sql-server-2008)

To DISABLE or REBUILD indexes, you can use below code from [SQL Server Blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/17/sql-server-disable-index-enable-index-alter-index/)

```
USE AdventureWorks
 GO
----Diable Index
ALTER INDEX [IX_StoreContact_ContactTypeID] ON Sales.StoreContact DISABLE
 GO
----Enable Index
ALTER INDEX [IX_StoreContact_ContactTypeID] ON Sales.StoreContact REBUILD
 GO
```

Comment: I know how to do this. My question is not related to this. I am asking about "WHEN INDEX DISABLED"not "HOW TO DISABLE".

Comment: @RohitKumar, I believe it is not possible to find out the date & time details of when the index disabled. As suggested by Ben Thul, setting Trigger or Event should work in this case.